# Can't Bind for successful connection

Tags: command-line, ldap

I am trying to test a connection to AD using OpenLDAP and this is what I try on the command line:

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -h names.myorg.com \
    -p 389 \
    -D "cn=conapps readonly,cn=users,dc=myorg,dc=com" \
    -LLL \
    -x \
    -b "ou=MyOrg Staff,ou=People,dc=myorg,dc=com" \
    -s sub "(objectClass=*)" DN sn givenName mail userPrincipalName employeeID usertype \
    -W
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Operations error (1)
Additional information: 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece
```

Can anybody see what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your password for bindDN is wrong, The bindDn which you are specifying is `cn=readonly,cn=users,dc=myorg,dc=com` and the password using `-W` is empty. It may be wrong and it is unable to authenticate you before doing a search.

Comment: -W according to the man page, is "Prompt for simple authentication." So, it should prompt me for it. Also, I had a typo in the example above but fixed it. the bindDn is: cn=conapps readonly,cn=users,dc=myorg,dc=com

Comment: Also, if I change to -w and provide the password on the command line, I get the same error message.

Comment: you should pass a `-` after `-W` and it will prompt for a password.

Answer (score 28):

Try port 3268 instead, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978012.aspx for more information

This command works for me:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap://test.com:3268 -dbc=test,dc=com -D 'DOMAIN\username' -W name=username dn
```

Comment: Thanks for this Lee. But, we've abandoned the project. I don't have a need anymore. :)

Comment: I had similar issue. `ldapsearch` was working fine with port `389`. When I tried to implement this using `python-ldap` the connection was timing out. Changing port to `3268` solved the issue

Comment: Same problem here. Changing to 3268 worked. Seems that different admins can configure their AD differently.

Comment: Is this the `ldapsearch` command from `openldap`? It seems to have different arguments in newer versions